# Access host network from container

Tags: docker

i got a service running on another machine on the same network, and i want my docker to access it's API

It's not an option to dockerize this service, so

**Is there a way to give this docker full access to the network ? Or at least this machine and it's coresponding port**

Comment: That should just work without any special configuration: your docker containers are already able to reach external sites. Just use the hostname or address of the remote machine.

Comment: (If a hostname, you will probably need a fully-qualified domain name `hostname.example.com`, lest Docker try to resolve a simple `hostname` as another container name.)

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but, i'm able to reach an url form my computer, but the docker can't.

That's why i'm asking

Thanks

Comment: I used the IPv4, should i use complete host name ?

Comment: I tried IPv4 hostname hostname.example.com nothing works i'm pretty lost

Comment: Maybe try with `--net=host`

Comment: How do you run the container currently, what is your `docker-compose.yml` file or `docker run ...` command?

Comment: I do docker build into docker run